# How does the C language support upper case letters without giving or providing information about upper case in program

Tags: c

```
#include<STDIO.H>
```

It  is in upper case but the program (compiles and) runs without any error in C language, but C is case sensitive — how this is possible?

```
#include<STDIO.H>
#include<CONIO.H>
main()
{
    printf("hello");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: 1) If this question is about C, why have you tagged C++? 2) Probably because your OS is case insensitive (probably - Windows).

Comment: Q: How is this possible?  A: the C compiler looks for a file named "stdio.h".  Windows (or DOS!) makes no distinction between "STDIO.H" and "stdio.h" ... so the compiler finds it.  This isn't a "C programming" issue; it's an "OS case sensitivity" issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works if you are using Windows or another operating system that ignores case on its file system. It doesn't work on Linux and other Unix flavours, because they do care about case (by default).

When you add an include statement like `#include <any_file.h>`, then the C-compiler will ask the operating system to open file `any_file.h`.

If your operating system doesn't care about case, then it will open any file that matches the pattern. If it, for instance, finds a file named `aNy_fILe.H`, it will open the file and present it to the C compiler.

The C-compiler will interpret the content of the file - this is the case-sensitive bit of the C language.